# SpringDoc: How to add description to body request parameters?

Tags: swagger, springdoc

In SpringDoc, you can use @Parameter to add descriptions and additional information for a query parameter. However, there doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to do it for parameters within a request body, especially for POST and PUT requests.

Is there a way to do this via annotations or is this a non-supported feature?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `@Schema` to your request body object in the individual fields.